# What is more reliable: editing element style or style tag?

Tags: javascript, css

I came across this question when trying to write a behavior: hover in javascript.

It feels like, for quite a few things, it is easy to write a new `<style>` tag with **new clases in javascript** rather than using the typical `element.style.property = "value";`

I find that the first way makes things easier for at least this cases:

- When you want to make `:hover` or `:active` behaviours, you can avoid listeners.
- When you have to deal with vendor prefixes. For example in cases like: `width: -webkit-calc(); width: -moz-calc();`

But there must be many disadvantages as well. I don't know of any for sure but my feelings is that this way may mess up with the css of the page, or maybe would be unable to write the `<style>` tag on the `<head>` correctly.

**So my question is: in case something can be done both ways, should I use the simpler one? Or is one of them far more reliable and, if I can, I should pick that one?**

Comment: Different situations call for different methods.  You might be writing pure javascript without access to modify the CSS for a site, in that situation it's easier to update styles directly rather than trying to inject CSS to the page then add a class etc.

Comment: I can see that! But what problems can I find when writing new style tags? So that I know when to avoid that method

Comment: I think injecting directly on element is more performant (but difference should be unnoticeable) ..

Comment: @maioman what about reliability?

Comment: I wouldn't know, both ways look pretty reliable; without evaluating the context it's hard to give advice . I'm sure that making an example case in which you are evaluating these 2 styling options would return some interesting answers..

Comment: @maioman What about a script that may be included in many different pages? Like a lightbox or something like that

Comment: in this case I'd use the inline-style option

Comment: but could you explain why?